# having an error in my code "NameError: name 'tweets_df' is not defined"

Tags: python, tweepy

I am having an error in my code that I couldn't solve

my code

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import tweepy as tw # To extarct the twitter data
from tqdm import tqdm

consumer_api_key = 'vJB7L6fhV3hYPQjXdgSDtzWdy'
consumer_api_secret = 'dUTeph2pJCaojtpuiv7M7UDLeEiuR6qTBhD0fOzdaTuOE8xTZF'

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_api_key, consumer_api_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

search_words = "#BTC #bitcoin -filter:retweets" #Type you keywork here instead of #covidvaccine
#You can fix a time frame with the date since and date until parameters
date_since = "2022-04-18"
date_until="2022-04-19"
# Collect tweets
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search_tweets,
              q=search_words,
              lang="en",
              since=date_since,
              until=date_until     
              ).items(7500) #We instruct the cursor to return maximum of 7500 tweets

tweets_copy = []
for tweet in tqdm(tweets):
    tweets_copy.append(tweet)

print(f"New tweets retrieved: {len(tweets_copy)}")

for tweet in tqdm(tweets_copy):
    hashtags = []
    try:
        for hashtag in tweet.entities["hashtags"]:
            hashtags.append(hashtag["text"])
    except:
        pass
    tweets_df = tweets_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'user_name': tweet.user.name, 
                                               'user_location': tweet.user.location,\
                                               'user_description': tweet.user.description,
                                               'user_created': tweet.user.created_at,
                                               'user_followers': tweet.user.followers_count,
                                               'user_friends': tweet.user.friends_count,
                                               'user_favourites': tweet.user.favourites_count,
                                               'user_verified': tweet.user.verified,
                                               'date': tweet.created_at,
                                               'text': tweet.text, 
                                               'hashtags': [hashtags if hashtags else None],
                                               'source': tweet.source,
                                               'is_retweet': tweet.retweeted}, index=[0]))

tweets_df

tweets_df.to_csv('newData.csv',index=False)
```

the error shoing when I try to run is

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 tweets_df

NameError: name 'tweets_df' is not defined

Comment: You didn't create tweets_df before appending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might creating a list of dataframes, then using the [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method to concatenate all list of dataframes into a single dataframe, something like

```py
tweets_df_list = []
for tweet in tqdm(tweets_copy):
    hashtags = []
    try:
        for hashtag in tweet.entities["hashtags"]:
            hashtags.append(hashtag["text"])
    except:
        pass
    tweets_df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'user_name': tweet.user.name, 
                                               'user_location': tweet.user.location,\
                                               'user_description': tweet.user.description,
                                               'user_created': tweet.user.created_at,
                                               'user_followers': tweet.user.followers_count,
                                               'user_friends': tweet.user.friends_count,
                                               'user_favourites': tweet.user.favourites_count,
                                               'user_verified': tweet.user.verified,
                                               'date': tweet.created_at,
                                               'text': tweet.text, 
                                               'hashtags': [hashtags if hashtags else None],
                                               'source': tweet.source,
                                               'is_retweet': tweet.retweeted}, index=[0]))
tweet_df = pd.concat(tweets_df_list)
tweets_df.to_csv('newData.csv',index=False)
```